# What is the most efficient way to query based on 3D Euclidean distance?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with X, Y, and Z coordinates. Each row of this table corresponds to a specific point in three space. Currently, this data is stored as three separate integer columns, but I can change that if need be.

I want to query this table to find the closest point given the input point (x, y, z). One naive way to do this would be to select `SQRT(POW((TableName.X - x), 2) + POW((TableName.Y - y), 2) + POW((TableName.Z - z), 2)) AS Distance` for each row in the table, and then select the row that has the smallest `Distance`.

I know MySQL has a `Point` data type, but I'm not sure if that will help here. Does anyone know of an efficient way to calculate Euclidean distance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL's `Point` has 2 coordinates, so it's good only for plane (2D) geometry, not 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by `POW((TableName.X - x), 2) + POW((TableName.Y - y), 2) + POW((TableName.Z - z), 2)` without the `SQRT`.

Since you only care about ordering, and the square root is monotone increasing, you can skip the square root.  Without the `SQRT`, the math should be fast enough.

Comment: It won't be very fast with a billion rows in the table though.

Comment: @ypercube: How expensive is multiplication? How much faster can you get without precomputing per-search?

Comment: I don't want to say that your answer is valueless. It does remove an unnecessary call to `SQRT()`. But it won't be very good if we have to search a big table (say 1G rows) - billion calls to `POW()` and billions of additions, then ordering. Or if we want to find for example the closest point to **every** point of a relatively small table (1M rows) - **trillion** calls to `POW()` and additions and then ordering.

Comment: If the Spatial Extensions included 3D points, the R-Tree index  structure would make such queries much faster. Which off course means a pre-computed index, especially tailored for such searches.

Comment: I wish there was a better solution, but this'll do. Thanks for the monotonic tip.

Answer (score 0):

One thing can be done is limit the x, y, z with its acceptable values.
This may reduce calculations for unnecessary records.
E.g. for maps one shows data points for a range of set of co-ordinates.