# MySQL - Calculating a 3D Distance for stored data?

Tags: mysql, 3d, game-engine

All-

I was just curious, I'm trying to basically calculate a distance to a multiple positions I have in a database, and was wondering if this is possible to do in a query?

I have maybe 7-9 million rows of positions (x, y, z, continent) and basically want to do a query like:

SELECT `positions` FROM `my_table` WHERE DISTANCE(x, y, z, new_x, new_y, new_z) < 500;

Does this even seem remotely possible? Or will I have to bring all the data down + do the calculations w/PHP? I've only seen it done w/GEO data vs. 3D coordinates.

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Comment: Just found this after more extensive googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704706/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-query-based-on-3d-euclidean-distance

Comment: How often do you want to run this query?

Comment: For 3D data in a database, you should also check Postgres (Gist) and SQLite (R-tree) implementations. I don't think MySQL has support for 3d spatial data and indices.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between objects in x,y,z is the difference between each coordinate of the two objects.

Distance between (x₁, y₁, z₁) and (x₂, y₂, z₂)

```
 (x₁-x₂, y₁-y₂, z₁-z₂)
```

The straight distance between the two points will be the root of the sum of the square of these values

```
 √((x₁-x₂)²+(y₁-y₂)²+(z₁-z₂)²)
```

Given some (X,Y,Z) coordinate, table "stars" with coordinate columns x, y and z, this might work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM stars
 WHERE SQRT(POWER(x-X,2)+POWER(y-Y,2)+POWER(z-Z,2)) < 500
```

Comment: Thank so much for posting this, it was exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly for me (including for negative yxz values).